# Handle decimal in jquery json

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I am retrieving some info through $.get from a ajax.php script. In the ajax.php script i get different numbers form a database which i want to update live on the site.

However, now i have run into the problem that some of the values that come from the DB are decimal ones, like: 0.79

When i JSON encode them in the ajax.php script they are returned fine for ex: o_epc:"0.71"
but for some reason my $.get doesent understand this value and returns it as null

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Here is my $.get call

```
                $.get("ajax.php", { opt: "networkStats", o_id: b }, function(r) {
                var j = eval('(' + r + ')');

                if(j.message) {
                    console.log(j.message);                     
                }
            });
```

This is how i encode my json

```
    $epc = (float) $db['o_epc'];

$RET['message']['o_epc'] = $epc;
die(json_encode($RET));
```

Answer (score 0):

If php is encoding them as `"0.71"`, then they've been converted to a string somewhere in your script. JSON allows bare numbers, but only if they're actually integers/floats. So check your script for things like sprintf() and numberformat(), which'd internally convert the value to a string.

Comment: i converted it to a float now by doing $floatVar = (float) $db['o_epc']; and it shows up without "" in json, but now my $.get is interpreting it as 0 instead of 0.71

Answer (score -1):

try encoding that way:

```
o_epc: 0.71
```

as http://json.org allows:

```
number
    int
    int frac
frac
    . digits
```